# How to register a unknown company for an known event participant?

Tags: civievent

we are using the civi event module and are currently registering participants for an event. Some of the participants replied that they will be accompanied by a friend or someone else without giving that persons name. Since we don't need these details really, we are searching for a way to register that first to us known person plus the unknown second participant. Has anyone an idea on that? Albeit what we need out of the civi event module at the end is a correct number of participants to plan the seats.

Thanks for looking into that problem. Best regards

Esther Reichert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got Erik right. If you want to get the correct number of participants from CiviCRM, you will probably have to use "dummies". If that is all you want, you wouldn't even need a relationship between them and the "real" participants.

In order to facilitate that, you could make a csv-sheet including 100 dummies using the columns First Name (Dummy1, Dummy2...), Last Name (Dummy1, Dummy2...) and E-Mail (dummy1@dummy.de...). You could then import the contacts into CiviCRM, give them a "dummy" tag at the same time and delete them after the event.

I have to admit, this is not the most elegant approach but as you kind of trick CiviCRM this is probably the price you'd have to pay ;)

If you are willing to do a bit of manual work, you could of course create a custom field asking "How many people will you bring along" and add up the numbers in the end. However, in that case, CiviCRM would obviously not display the right number of participants but you would have to calculate yourself.

Comment: Thank you to both of you, actually that's the road we're going to take!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like using a Price Set that allows the user to enter the number of people coming as an integer. Set the Price Set field to count each as a participant, then you will get your total number.

Comment: That probably would have worked as well - we already missused the civi Price Set in other cases. Thank you for contributing!

Comment: It is a solution we have used in a scenario where Person X books a 'group tour' for eg 10 people, but we only get the name of Person X, and we want to report at month end how many people took the tour, so it works well, and probably doesn't count as Price Set Abuse in this instance ;-) (though many other things we do might)

Comment: Civi need creativity sometimes :) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you manually registering the participants or are they registering themselves from a registration page? If the first is the case, you could create a dummy contact and company with something like 'Second' in the name?

Comment: thanks for your swift reply. We register them manually. I'm not sure that I understand you properly: You recommend to create a dummy "second" contact and pair it with the known contact, right? We thought about that too, although the problem is that you can register every contact - that means "dummy second" likewise - only once. That would mean we had to create a dummy second for everyone who is accompanied by an unknown person. But so far we have discarded that option as it would create an immense data trash in Civi - which would be useless after the event. Have I gotten your point? Best regar

Comment: I meant what Fabian explained :-) Not the best, but if it works for you....And my suggestion was to name the second 'John Doe Second' if the first was 'John Doe'. If you want to 'link' them I guess you mean you want to link both to one organization with a relatiosnhip?If not, can you expand a little?

Comment: We wanted to link the unknown person to the known person so that we see due to whom they are registered. But we named them only Dummy 1, 2, and so forth, so that it is very obvious that they are no real characters - and easy to deleate after the event.